# Exception sql request oracle ora 920

Tags: c#, oracle

I get an error  ORA-00920 invalid relational operator on the next request

```
foreach (DataRow rowOut in dsOut.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        var uwi = rowOut.Field<String>("uwi");
        var top = rowOut.Field<Decimal>("t");
        var bottom = rowOut.Field<Decimal>("b");

        commandText = "select udmurtneft_n.dg_des(ws.layer_id) from " +
                      "udmurtneft_n.well_log_result_sublayers ws " +
                    "where ws.uwi = '" + uwi + "' " +
                    "and (("+top+ " >= ws.top and "+top+" < ws.base) or " +
                    "("+bottom+" > ws.top and " + bottom+" <= ws.base) or " +
                    "(ws.top >= "+top+ " and ws.top < "+bottom+") or " +
                    "(ws.base > "+top+" and ws.base <= " + bottom+"))";
        DataSet dsOutLayer = null;
        var flagLayer = dataBase.GetData(commandText, cancelToken, out dsOutLayer);

    }
```

Comment: `top` and `bottom` need to be enclosed in single quotes `(')` just like you did it for `uwi`

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980, Are you sure? uwi has a type String

Answer (score 1):

If you have decimal values you may have a problem with your decimal separator. Example : if by concatening `top` you get

```sql
and ((4,5 >= ws.top and 4,5 < ws.base) or
```

and not

```sql
and ((4.5 >= ws.top and 4.5 < ws.base) or
```

you will have a syntax error. You should at least use the Oracle `TO_NUMBER()` function in your sql to have

```sql
and ((TO_NUMBER('4,5') >= ws.top and TO_NUMBER('4,5') < ws.base) or
```

But this will not be enough to solve your problem, because if the separator defined in your db session is `,` and you send `TO_NUMBER('4.5')` you will get a cast error.
So you have to handle the decimal separator when you concatenate your value so that it matches the separator expected by Oracle.
The other (and cleaner) way is to use queries with parameters such as :

```cs
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT  udmurtneft_n.dg_des(ws.layer_id) FROM  udmurtneft_n.well_log_result_sublayers ws WHERE ws.uwi=:uwi + AND :top >= ws.top ", dbConnection);
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("uwi", uwi));
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("top", top));
```